# Can't run the server side of my project on render.com

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, github, render.com

I have a fully working React project that runs server with Express and gets data from mongodb. I made deploy on my repo in github and then created an account in render.com, connected my repo with render and chose Web Service which should run the backend. In the column Build command I pointed npm run build and in Start command I chose npm run server (that runs my server) and then I tried to build my app but I keep getting this kind of error:

```
...
Jun 20 12:35:24 AM  ==> Running build command 'npm run build'...
Jun 20 12:35:25 AM  
Jun 20 12:35:25 AM  > for@0.1.0 build /opt/render/project/src
Jun 20 12:35:25 AM  > react-scripts build
Jun 20 12:35:25 AM  
Jun 20 12:35:25 AM  sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
Jun 20 12:35:25 AM  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
Jun 20 12:35:25 AM  npm ERR! syscall spawn
Jun 20 12:35:25 AM  npm ERR! file sh
Jun 20 12:35:25 AM  npm ERR! errno ENOENT
Jun 20 12:35:25 AM  npm ERR! for@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
Jun 20 12:35:25 AM  npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
Jun 20 12:35:25 AM  npm ERR!
Jun 20 12:35:25 AM  npm ERR! Failed at the for@0.1.0 build script.
Jun 20 12:35:25 AM  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
Jun 20 12:35:25 AM  
Jun 20 12:35:25 AM  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
Jun 20 12:35:25 AM  npm ERR!     /opt/render/.cache/_logs/2023-06-19T21_35_25_190Z-debug.log
Jun 20 12:35:25 AM  ==> Build failed
```

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "for",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "homepage": "https://stas9909.github.io/new-delivery-mongo-express",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.2",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "axios": "^1.2.6",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "express": "^4.18.2",
        "formik": "^2.2.9",
        "mongodb": "^5.6.0",
        "mongoose": "^7.2.3",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.8.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "redux": "^4.2.1",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
        "yup": "^0.32.11"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "predeploy": "npm run build",
        "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
        "server": "node server/server.js",
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "serve": "start /B npm run server & npm run start",
        "startboth": "concurrently \"npm start\" \"npm run server\"",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
        "react-app",
        "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "concurrently": "^8.2.0",
        "gh-pages": "^5.0.0"
    }
}
```

Has anyone come across a similar issue and knows how to fix it?

I deleted my `package-lock.json`, `node_modules` and `build` folder, re-created them and repeated all over again but the problem is still the same. I can't even imagine what could be the reason, because locally my app works perfectly

Comment: Try exchange Build command for `npm install`.

Comment: Second thing about your Start command: does your current `npm run server` runs into any error or is that your current setup? *I don't know if you have modified `package.json` to include `server` property?* Otherwise, it should be `npm start`

Comment: I did it with npm install. As for the second, not sure if I understood correctly, but I could run my app by doing npm start (runs client) and npm run server ("server": "node server/server.js") and everything works. My github must run client and render must run exactly the server side, for which the command npm run server is responsible - that's why i indicated npm run server as Start command in render.com

Comment: Build & Deploy (render.com):                                                                                                                                              
Branch: gh-pages;                                                                                                                     
Build Command: npm run build;                                                                                               
Start Command: npm run server;                                                                                              
Auto-Deploy: yes

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant if you have `"server": "node server/server.js"` inside `package.json` then it should be fine running `npm run server`. Anyways, I didn't understand did `npm install` as the Build Command fixed the issue already or does the issue persists?

Comment: Thanks. When I changed npm run build to npm install I got "Build successful"